# Reading all arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Im making a simple validation form system (over my raw php MCV framework) on PHP but Im having an issue I cant fix

I have this code

```
        $credentials = array('name' => 'required', 'password' => 'required|between');

    $validator = new Validation;
    if (!$validator->check($credentials, array(5, 10))) Redirect::to('/login', 'error', $validator->msg);
```

Then my class calidator looks like

```
public function check($fields, $size)
{
    foreach ($fields as $key => $val)
    {
        $rule = explode('|', $val);

        if (in_array('required', $rule))
        {
            if (empty($_POST[$key])) 
            {
                $this->msg = 'Field '.$key.' is required';
                $this->final = false;
            }
        }
        elseif (in_array('between', $rule))
        {
            if (strlen($_POST[$key]) < $size[0])
            {
                $this->msg = 'Filed '.$key.' must be between '.$size[0].' and '.$size[1].' chars';
                $this->final = false;
            }

            if (strlen($_POST[$key]) > $size[1])
            {
                $this->msg = 'Filed '.$key.' must be between '.$size[0].' and '.$size[1].' chars';
                $this->final = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$final)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The thing is that when I send the array like this ( with just 1 rule )

```
$credentials = array('name' => 'required', 'password' => 'between');
```

It works fine but if I add more rules (required|between ...) my function will just work with the first one so in this case the between rule is ignored...

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `elseif` with `if`:

```
if (in_array('required', $rule))
{
    if (empty($_POST[$key])) 
    {
        $this->msg = 'Field '.$key.' is required';
        $this->final = false;
    }
}
// Change this elseif
elseif (in_array('between', $rule))
```

It's the meaning of `elseif` that causes only the first rule to be checked. if you have `'required|between'` then the first if statement will be entered, so the `elseif` portion cannot be.